# Why Altium AC simulation lacks of the math functions available in other analyses?

Tags: simulation, altium, math

In Altium Designer, Mixed Sim simulation, AC analysis, the plots can be modified adding arbitrary combination of waveforms, but for some reason, the Edit Waveform dialog lacks of the mathematical functions available in other types of analysis. Why??

In AC analysis this is the dialog
[image]

In the other hand, in transient analysis the dialog has a lot of math functions available in other analyses too.

[image]

Comment: What version of Altium is this?

Comment: I'm using the version 20, but it's the same in older versions, I just updated the images